# Curiosity: $\text{antiprime} = \text{prime} + 1$

Tags: prime-numbers, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization

The following is just a mathematical curiosity that popped into my head that I thought was interesting. I haven't been able to find anything about it online, although maybe I just am unaware of the terminology.

One of my favorite numbers is $23$ since $23$ itself is prime yet $24 = 23+1$ is [antiprime (or highly composite although I find the name antiprime more catchy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number). It then occurred to me that quite a few of the twenty smallest antiprimes are one more than a prime:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{antiprime} & \text{antiprime}-1 \\
\hline
1 & \color{red}0 \\
2 & \color{red}1 \\
4 & \color{blue}3 \\
6 & \color{blue}5 \\
12 & \color{blue}{11} \\
24 & \color{blue}{23} \\
36 & \color{red}{35} & \\
48 & \color{blue}{47} \\
60 & \color{blue}{59} \\
120 & \color{red}{119} \\
180 & \color{blue}{179} \\
240 & \color{blue}{239} \\
360 & \color{blue}{359} \\
720 & \color{blue}{719} \\
840 & \color{blue}{839} \\
1260 & \color{blue}{1259} \\
1680 & \color{red}{1679} \\
2520 & \color{red}{2519} \\
5040 & \color{blue}{5039} \\
7560 & \color{blue}{7559} \\
\end{array}
$$
where blue denotes prime while red denotes not prime. Since many results are known about antiprimes and many more, of course, are known about primes, I'd like to ask the community the following questions.

1. Is this just an anomaly due to only having checked the first few antiprimes?
2. Are there infinitely many antiprimes that are one more than a prime?
3. As a follow up two question 2,  does anyone know of an algorithm to generate antiprimes that are one more than a prime? I only ask since results are known about the prime facotrizations of antiprimes, so maybe particular factorizations may be of use.
4. I guess the notion of antiprimes and primes are well-defined in a [unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) that is also an [ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring). So maybe any results in the usual case of the integers can be generalized to such ordered UFDs?
5. Lastly, is there already a name for such antiprime-prime pairs? If not, what should we call them? :)

Again this is just a fun curiosity that I thought I'd ask the community. I have thought a bit about these questions but I have not been able to come up with any results. If anyone has any other interesting questions about these antiprime-prime pairs or know of interesting results that I haven't asked about, please feel free to drop them below.

Comment: It seems that [Prime Numbers Generated From
Highly Composite Numbers](https://www.parabola.unsw.edu.au/files/articles/2010-2019/volume-54-2018/issue-3/vol54_no3_4.pdf) talks about that. Other references in https://oeis.org/A002182 might also be useful.

Comment: Well, it's hardly surprising that highly composite numbers should be divisible by lots of small primes, which would tend to rule out a lot of natural prime factors for its nearest neighbors.  I suggest broadening your search to require either $n-1$ or $n+1$ to be prime.  Then, if it looks interesting, see if $n-1$ is prime more frequently than $n+1$ is.  But you will want to search out fairly far to avoid oddities attached to small numbers.

Comment: As a heuristic, if $n$ is not, say, divisible by $2,3,5,$ we’d expect $n$ to be a prime with approximately the probability $$\prod_{7\leq p<\sqrt n}\frac{p-1}p$$ So if $m<17^2$ and divisible by $30,$ then $m-1$ would have rough probability of being prime about $\frac67\frac{10}{11}\frac{12}{13}\approx 0.72.$  You actually get $3/4$ for the antiprimes in that range, but we actually get a higher probability when $n<169$ and $n<121.$ So this doesn’t seem unusual. Antiprimes $m$ tend to have a lot of the smallest primes as prime factors, which makes it more likely they that $m-1$ is prime.

Comment: If $n$ is relatively prime to $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$ and $n<37^2$ the probability estimate is $0.69.$  You have two such numbers in that range, so it really isn’t odd that both of them are prime, especially since $840$ actually has a higher probability.

Comment: A slightly cruder estimate, if $n$ is not divisible by any of $2,3,5,7,$ the probability that $n$ is prime is roughly $$\frac1{\log n}\cdot \frac 21\cdot \frac 32\cdot \frac54\cdot\frac76=\frac{105}{24\log n}.$$ When $n=7560,$ that comes to about $0.49,$ and higher for smaller values. So the fact that half of them are prime for the last few is close to right

Comment: Now the question is, when is the first anti prime divisible by $11?$ Do new prime factors get added consistently in a way that lets you predict how this probability changes?

Comment: I do not think that "antiprime" is a common terminology. Call them just highly composite numbers. They are known upto a very high limit, just check in which cases we get a prime if we subtract $1$ (the same question can be made for the case that we add $1$ , or even when the highly composite number is surrounded by two (twin) primes)

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your comments

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, may I ask how you are calculating these probabilities? Is it using the prime number theorem? Or is it much more simple than that?

Comment: The first examples use an intuitive idea. The example with $\log n$ in the denominator uses the prime number theorem. Neither of these are really probabilities, just “heuristics,” as in, “If we picked a random number about the size of $n$ and we knew it was not divisible by $2,3,5,7,$ what is the chance that it is prime?” It gives us a sense of how “surprised” we should be by these frequencies, but is far from a rigorous argument.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see, thank you for explaining. In my free time I'll try to think about these probabilities and the questions i asked more